# It does not call the page in php

Tags: php

I am having a problem when I`m trying to open a page in php.
I have a created page contact.php which when a call in another php file(index.php) like

```
 <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
```

it works, but when I write

```
  <li><a href="/index.php?cmd=contact">Contact</a></li>
```

it is appearing in url but the page is not found!
I know that the problem is in configuration but how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't work this way. `index.php` does not know what you want to do with the passed `GET` argument `cmd`. If you want to have an index controller to behave like this:

```php
<li><a href="/index.php?cmd=contact">Contact</a></li>
```

then you have to create that kind of controller.

For example, make the `index.php` look like this if you want to control which files you are going to load:

```php
if(isset($_GET['cmd'])) {
    $cmd = $_GET['cmd'];

    switch($cmd) {
        case 'contact':
            include 'contact.php';
            return;
    }
}
```

or make it look like this if you have multiple php files:

```php
if(isset($_GET['cmd'])) {
    $cmd = $_GET['cmd'];
    $file = "{$cmd}.php";

    if(file_exists($file)) {
        include $file;
        return;
    }
}
```